# add link to head in perl cgi

Tags: perl, cgi

I'm new to Perl, and I'm trying to include a CSS file in a perl-generated html page,
how can I do that with cgi ?
it should be something like 
print $cgi -> start_html( -link => { -href => '/styles/main.css', -rel => 'stylsheet', -type => 'text/css'});

Here's the full code,

```
#!C:\Dwimperl\perl\bin\perl.exe
use CGI;
my $cgi = new CGI;

# ###----- GETTING THE SCRIPTS AND STYLES ------###
my $jquery = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js";

# ###----- PRINTING THE PAGE -----###
print   $cgi -> header;
print   $cgi -> start_html(
            -title => "TestTitle",
            -link => { -href => '/styles/main.css', -rel => 'stylsheet', -type => 'text/css'},
            -script=> [{-language => 'javascript',-src => $jquery},{-code => $jscript}],
        );
print   $cgi -> h1({-class=>"title",-align=>"center"},"Zero Testing");
print   $cgi -> start_div({-align=>"center"});
print   $cgi -> start_div({-align=>"center",-style=>"margin-bottom:35px;"});
print   $cgi -> a({-class=>"linkButton",-id=>"btn_Page",-href=>"Test.pl"},"Suites Page");
print   $cgi -> end_div;
print   $cgi -> start_form({-method=>"get",-id=>"dataForm"});
print   $cgi -> end_form;
print   $cgi -> end_div;
print   $cgi -> end_html();
```

Thanks

Comment: You really don't want to use CGI.pm to generate your HTML. It's a much better idea to put your HTML in a template.

Answer (score 2):

You could write this:

```
use CGI qw/:standard/;

# ...     

print $cgi->start_html(
   -title =>"TestTitle",
   -script=> [ {-language => 'javascript',-src => $jquery}, {-code => $jscript} ],
   -head => [
      Link( { -href => '/styles/main.css', -rel => 'stylsheet', -type => 'text/css'}),
    ]
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did as you mentioned up there but all I get is a white screen with no elements inside..

Comment: did you init the $jscript variable properly ?